# method: SciPy.optimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I wrote the following code to minimize objective where the variables `x1`, `x2`, `x3` are between 0.8-1.2 and the sum of `x1`, `x2`, `x3` is a number.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize 


def objective(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    x3 = x[2]
    return 1/x1 +2/x3+ 0.5/x2

def constraint1(x):
    return 7*x[0]+8*x[1]+4*x[2]-5

x0 = [1,0.8, 1.1]
b = (0.8, 1.2)
bnds = (b,b,b)
con1 = {'type':'eq', 'fun' :constraint1}

solution = minimize(objective, x0, method ='', bounds= bnds, constraints= con1)

print (solution)
```

I used the BFGS function which gave me an array that is outside the range of 0.8-1.2 while SLSQP gave me `success=false`. Is there something wrong with my code or am I using the wrong method?

Answer (score 1):

- BFGS is not for constrained problems
- With SLSQP I saw: message: 'Iteration limit exceeded'
- After increasing the iteration limit: message: 'Inequality constraints incompatible'
- That makes sense. How can `7*x[0]+8*x[1]+4*x[2]=5` if the lower bounds on the variables are 0.8? I.e. we know in advance that `7*x[0]+8*x[1]+4*x[2]>=15.2`.

I suggest providing this method with feasible problems.

Comment: Thank you Erwin, yes I used random numbers in there.

Comment: Random problems are often infeasible